# How to create responsive navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code where I intend to have a responsive navbar. It displays properly in big screens but for some reason is not collapsing in small screens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleanalytics.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3.jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

How can I make the toggle button collapse?

https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/8wncr2dm/

Comment: Your link to jQuery script is broken.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8wncr2dm/3/

Comment: Is there a way to alter the breakpoint of the navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Just used incorrect version for jQuery Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

try to include https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling jQuery correctly. Inspecting your Fiddle shows this:

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

It looks like the domain you're using is incorrect, and you're misplacing a slash for a dot. Try this instead:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -1):

Not a problem in your bootstrap code. Just the `jquery cdn` that you are using in script tag of your code is not working. Use a different `cdn` instead.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

Edit your script tag as

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
```

Comment: There is a problem in his code, the link he provided is wrong, and returns a 404 error.

Comment: @Lee which link are you talking about

Comment: The call to jQuery

Comment: @Lee Yeah thats what I meant by my answer that you need to use a seperate cdn not the one that you are using. His code doesn't have any errors. Rather his script url is not functional. Read the answer properly before downvoting and commenting

Comment: Yes it does have errors, the link is incorrect. It's got nothing to do with the choice of CDN. Using a different CDN is not the fix, correcting the URL is the fix. I can read perfectly well thank you. Downvote staying.